# Error 1 error C2259: 'Player' : cannot instantiate abstract class

Tags: c++

Why I can't I instantiate? Why is player is an abstract class?
Have I declared the pure virtual function in base class only?

```
class Object
{
protected:
public:
    virtual void DrawOnScreen() = 0;
};

class Creature : public Object
{
public:
    virtual void DrawOnScreen()=0;
    virtual  void Eat(Object*)=0;
    virtual void move(Direction)=0;
};

class Player : public Creature
{
    void Player::DrawOnScreen()
    {
        cout << "position= (" << get_x() << "," << get_y() << ")" << endl << "player's score " << points << endl;
        if (get_isKilled()) cout << "It is Killed " << endl;
        else cout << "It is Alive " << endl;
    }

    void Player::eat(Object* p)
    {
        Point* chk;
        chk = dynamic_cast<Point*>(p);
        if ((chk != 0) && (get_x() == chk->get_x()) && (get_y() == chk->get_y()) && (chk - > get_isExist()))
        {
            points = points + chk->get_weight();
            chk->set_isExist(false);
        }
    }

    void Player::move(Direction d)
    {
        if (d == UP)
        {
            y = y + 2;
        }
        if (d == DOWN)
        {
            y = y - 2;
        }
        if (d == RIGHT)
        {
            x = x + 2;
        }
        if (d == LEFT)
        {
            x = x - 2;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I'm sure the error message lists the exact pure functions you did not override resp. did not implement.

Comment: C++ is case sensitive. Write eat and move with upper case

Comment: @slfan: move is compilable as is, albeit inconsistent. It does not clash with std::move either.

Comment: @LaszloPapp: you're right, I thought move was uppercase in the base class as well. My comment is just for eat and this is the reason why the class Player is abstract.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The problem is that you cannot instantiate a class with at least one pure virtual method which is happening in here due to the inheritance and mistaken override.

That is a typo:

```
void Player::eat(Object*p)
```

You really meant "Eat" with capital, hence you are not actually overriding. You should have written this:

```
void Player::Eat(Object*p)
```

On top of that, you really should remove the `Player::` scoping for the methods within the class, or move the methods like that outside.

Also, Please make a great use of the C++11 override keyword to avoid such issues, so something like this would give you a compilation error:

```
void Eat(Object *p) override;
```